# How to remove some extra space at bottom in QMChatViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, quickblox, q-municate

I am using QuickBlox Q-municate for my chat application and after set up Q-municate in my application in swift, i am getting some extra space at bottom. I tried with different solution provided in code but not able to remove that space.

Please help me on this how can i remove that space.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override "inputToolBarStartPos" method which is used in the QMChatViewController.

For Swift

```
-(NSUInteger)inputToolBarStartPos {
 return 0;
}
```

For Objective C

```
@objc func inputToolBarStartPos() -> Int{
return 0;
}
```

[Original answer](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/issues/965)